Pnp transistor blocking back feed current on collector side?
Why can't I use a pnp transistor as a switch to send voltage to a battery to start charging it (the details of the charging circuit is limting current, so no damage to transistor. I Just need the transistor details for this part of design), but don't want to use a blocking diode when the transistor is off? Because pnp transistors have a vcbo rating about the same as vceo rating, and if collector voltage side is higher than emitter side then it does not conduct as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you draw a schematic showing the exact condition you are trying to explain, and trying to avoid/solve, and tell us why a diode would/wouldn't work?


don't want to use a blocking diode when the transistor is off

As long as you can assure that the charger and the battery have correct polarity, there's no need for a blocking diode in the high current path. Typical charger designs will work within these constraints. You do need a base-protecting diode though.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In the circuit above, D2 protects the battery against over-discharge. D3 protects against reverse-connected charger. D1 limits the reverse base-emitter voltage of Q1. Q3/Q2 are a current source that produce the base current needed to turn Q1 on. The control voltage comes from a 3.3V logic output from an MCU - I presume that's of some use. For higher control voltages, increase R1 proportionally with the control voltage.
F1 protects the charger, control and load circuits from fire in case there was a short in any of them.

This pretty much answered my question. Thanks.
